# AWS Sagemaker IDE Data Science 3.0 image has numerous dependency conflicts

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

The Data Science 3.0 image is unusable for me since importing and attempting to install new packages via pip returns a whole host of dependency errors

My question is, I can't find any mention of this issue anywhere, am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to use this?

Example:
Step 1: I wish to install sagemaker experiments, I run `!pip install sagemaker-experiments`.
It returns

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
distributed 2022.7.0 requires tornado<6.2,>=6.0.3, but you have tornado 6.3.2 which is incompatible.
```

Step 2: I attempt to update distributed, I run `!pip install distributed`.
It returms

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 5.3.3 requires pyqt5<5.16, which is not installed.
spyder 5.3.3 requires pyqtwebengine<5.16, which is not installed.
jupyter-client 8.3.0 requires tornado>=6.2, but you have tornado 6.1 which is incompatible.
jupyter-server 2.7.0 requires tornado>=6.2.0, but you have tornado 6.1 which is incompatible.
jupyterlab 3.4.4 requires jupyter-server~=1.16, but you have jupyter-server 2.7.0 which is incompatible.
jupyterlab-server 2.10.3 requires jupyter-server~=1.4, but you have jupyter-server 2.7.0 which is incompatible.
notebook 6.5.5 requires jupyter-client<8,>=5.3.4, but you have jupyter-client 8.3.0 which is incompatible.
notebook 6.5.5 requires pyzmq<25,>=17, but you have pyzmq 25.1.0 which is incompatible.
panel 0.13.1 requires bokeh<2.5.0,>=2.4.0, but you have bokeh 3.2.1 which is incompatible.
sagemaker-datawrangler 0.4.3 requires sagemaker-data-insights==0.4.0, but you have sagemaker-data-insights 0.3.3 which is incompatible.
spyder 5.3.3 requires ipython<8.0.0,>=7.31.1, but you have ipython 8.14.0 which is incompatible.
spyder 5.3.3 requires pylint<3.0,>=2.5.0, but you have pylint 3.0.0a6 which is incompatible.
spyder-kernels 2.3.3 requires ipython<8,>=7.31.1; python_version >= "3", but you have ipython 8.14.0 which is incompatible.
spyder-kernels 2.3.3 requires jupyter-client<8,>=7.3.4; python_version >= "3", but you have jupyter-client 8.3.0 which is incompatible.
```

I have had this situation occur with multiple packages I wish to install or import, there's even an error when importing numpy.

Comment: Importing numpy should work by default, but I wonder if the other installed packages are conflicting with numpy version as well. Can you try the newly launched SageMaker Distribution image instead, I was able to install and import experiments on that image.

Comment: Also, sagemaker-experiments is part of the SageMaker SDK now, so you can now simply import like `from sagemaker.experiments.run import Run, load_run`. See example notebook - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-experiments/local_experiment_tracking/pytorch_experiment.ipynb